# Can you get reconstructive surgery in Mass Effect 3?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Mass Effect 2 let you permanently reverse the red Lazarus scars being a Renegade gives you.

Does Mass Effect 3 have an option to do this? If so, when can I get/unlock the surgery and how much does it cost? At what point in the game does the option become available?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order to get the **Med Bay Surgery** Intel Upgrade, you'll first need to complete the mission **Priority:Citadel** (the second one, which follows Tuchanka). After the events on the Citadel, when you return to the Normandy, your Ships doctor will have a request for you in the med bay -  she wants you to negotiate with a Turian in the Citadels refugee camp area to exchange their excess medical supplies for the Normandys excesses.

Once you make a deal, when you return to the Normandy, your ships doctor will award you with some credits, a Medi-Gel upgrade, and inform you that there's an upgrade availiable at the terminal in Liara's quarters. At this point, you can take the **Med Bay Surgery** upgrade, which offers you a choice between **Facial Reconstruction** to heal Shepards scars, or a **Health Bonus** of 5%.

This upgrade costs nothing.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you will eventually get a piece of intel which unlocks a 5% health boost or healing your Lazarus scarring.

To clarify, intel unlocks research projects in Liara's quarters.

Comment: I believe I got it fairly late into the game, about the time you do the second Priority: Citadel mission, and I tend to do all the sidequests as they become available. If somebody could pinpoint the location, that would be ace.