# What is the impact of not having a ship's doctor?

Tags: mass-effect-3

According to the answers on my [earlier question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/55644/10260) I may have missed my opportunity to have a ship's doctor on board the Normandy.

What are the ramifications of not having a doctor on board?  Could I potentially lose crew members?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I doubt it. Dr. Chakwas did basically nothing except when I spoke to her, and even then it was just character development stuff. It didn't seem like she really played a role in anything at all.

Comment: I remember Dr. Chakwas had a mission of some kind to swap medical supplies somewhere, I think it added some war assets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll miss out on a Medi-Gel upgrade (either capacity or amount healed per use), as well as [the opportunity to heal Shepards facial scars](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/55250/3129) if you're playing a Renegade.

Beyond that, there should be no other consequence, aside from a few missed conversations with minor opportunities to earn Reputation and/or Paragon/Renegade points (+2 max each time).

Answer (score 1):

If you have Chakwas on board the Normandy, she will offer you a side quest later to trade some supplies with the refugees on the Citadel. She will also allow you to upgrade your medigel later in the game.

If you don't take Chakwas, then she is a war asset (worth 25 points IIRC).

Comment: My previous playthrough was with Dr. Michel, and I seem to remember I had this "supplies" mission, too. Looking at the Mass Effect Wiki confirms this: http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Citadel:_Medical_Supplies

Answer (score 0):

Aas far as I know the only thing you will miss out on is what "yx" said about missing out on a side mission. The mission is on the citadel to talk to a person to swap medical supplies. It increases the alliance numbers because of better medicine.

Comment: I think this mission is balanced by the War Asset you get for having Chakwas stay behind and work in R&D but I'd have to recheck that.